# How to edit textlabel created automatically in a new cell after using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

[image]

The Cell with Identifier **"home"** has a `textlabel` and `imageview`. I want to edit the content of the label in the newly created prototype cell which are formed after using the function `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. Don't insert source code as image, but as formatted text.

Comment: Kindly complete your question. What do u need exactly? do you need data from a array ? data from server  ? or just hard coded data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use tag property to distinguish the label you want as follows.

1) Set tag of the label in different cells to 1 (or any number you like).

2) After getting the cell use:

```
UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
myLabel.text = @"Whatever I like";
```